# Laravel routes work on localhost but not on IP address

Tags: php, apache, url-routing, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm having a problem that just appeared this morning. I'm writing a large application using Laravel 5.2. I'm developing on a Windows 7 computer using Aptana Studio 3 with the UwAmp wamp server. I'm two months into development and until today everything has been working well. I have been able to fully use my site when visiting http://localhost/ and also when using my PC's IP address from both my PC and other PCs on the network. My most recent sub-project has been a built in chat client for my site using a lot of AJAX. I made a controller specifically to handle the chat AJAX and corresponding routes. Starting this morning, on http://localhost/ everything works as expected, but when I try to access using the IP address (from either my development PC or other PCs on the network) I can visit only my root page (the '/' route). All other routes (including the Laravel provided Auth routes) display this message: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`.
I cannot figure out what I did to cause this. I have spent hours this morning scouring my code and proofreading to make sure I didn't misspell, neglect capitalization, or forget a semicolon. Most of what I've found on the internet has been related to .htaccess or Apache configs. I'm certain it's not an Apache issue because it was working fine a few days ago and also the error page is a standard gray Laravel style error page. I have already tried clearing the route cache with artisan and also have tried changing my APP_URL in .env to my IP address instead of localhost, neither worked. Has anyone else ran into this type of issue? Can you offer any insight please?

Here is a condensed snippet from my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    //Other routes here
    Route::post('/chat/users_ajax', 'ChatController@users_ajax');
    Route::post('/chat/conversations_ajax', 'ChatController@conversations_ajax');
    Route::post('/chat/start_ajax', 'ChatController@start_ajax');
    Route::post('/chat/get_conversation_ajax', 'ChatController@get_conversation_ajax');
    Route::post('/chat/send_ajax', 'ChatController@send_ajax');
    //More routes here
    Route::get('/auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('/auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
});
```

and here is the error and stack trace:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: paste your middleware, also the path you hitting

Comment: Try removing `['middleware' => 'web']` as its by default invoked in `RouteServiceProvider`

Comment: I assume you are referring to the middleware groups array in Kernel.php:`     protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];`

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. And I was pretty upset. Apparently Laravel routes are case sensitive. When I was typing my URLs into the address bar, I was using all lowercase. My bad guys, but thanks for your help anyway. I appreciate you taking the time to consider my issue.